# Getting index out of bound error in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of list in Python

```
table = [[30,100],[25,100],[20,100],[15,00],[10,100],[5,100]]
```

Now I want to implement a logic like below, if 30 > 25 then divide first list second value (100) by 2 and add that value to second list second value (100 + 50) and so on , so in the end result should be like below

[30 , 50]
[25, 75]
[20, 87.5]

and so on. I have done like below

```
table = [[30,100],[25,100],[20,100],[15,00],[10,100],[5,100]]

print len(table)

for i in range(len(table)):
    print i
    if  table[i][0] > table[i+1][0]:
        table[i][1] = table[i][1]/2
        table[i+1][1]=table[i+1][1] + table[i][1]
        print table[i][0] , table[i][1]



from pprint import pprint
pprint(table)
```

but getting error

```
    if  table[i][0] > table[i+1][0]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: value doesn't exist for `i+1` for last element in your list.

Comment: You can do this operation only for `for i in range(len(table)-1):` else you are trying to add/test something against an element that is _after_ your list ends

Comment: @ patrick thanks for pointing out my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is are trying to iterate to full length of the table array, should be the length of the array minus one. As index starts at zero.

Also note another reason: you wouldn't be able to apply your logic to the last element as it is the last element in the list, there would be no n+1 element to apply it to.

```
table = [[30,100],[25,100],[20,100],[15,00],[10,100],[5,100]]

print len(table)

for i in range(len(table)-1):
    print i
    if  table[i][0] > table[i+1][0]:
        table[i][1] = table[i][1]/2
        table[i+1][1]=table[i+1][1] + table[i][1]
        print table[i][0] , table[i][1]



from pprint import pprint
pprint(table)
```